# Convert a C# line to PHP

Tags: c#, php, md5

I have the following function in C#:

```
    static MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    public string Guid GetMD5(string str)
    {
        lock (md5Provider)
        {
            return (new Guid(md5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)))).ToString();
        }
    }
```

I need the same code but with PHP.
Note that the md5() function has a different behavior.

thx

Comment: md5 function has the same behavior everywhere. If you get different outputs, then you've got different inputs. e.g. you're doing utf-8 in one place, but iso-8859 in another - md5 works on raw bytes, not characters.

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)` returns the bytes representing `str` using UTF-16LE encoding.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it's probably an encoding problem. I'm still not able to reproduce this function with PHP.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the issue you are having is that the C# code returns the hash separated with dashes, because you are converting the hash to a GUID, and [`GUID.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/560tzess.aspx) returns the string in what M$ call "registry format", which is the standard 8-4-4-4-12 string notation of a GUID.

If this is the case, you could achieve the same result with this function:

```
function md5_guid ($data, isFile = FALSE) {
  if ($isFile) {
    if (is_file($data) && is_readable($data)) {
      $hash = str_split(md5_file($data), 4);
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  } else {
    $hash = str_split(md5($data), 4);
  }
  return "$hash[0]$hash[1]-$hash[2]-$hash[3]-$hash[4]-$hash[5]$hash[6]$hash[7]";
}


// Returns the MD5 hash of the string 'this is some data' in the format of a GUID
echo md5_guid('this is some data');

// Returns the MD5 hash of the file at 'somefile.txt' in the format of a GUID
echo md5_guid('somefile.txt', TRUE);
```

Comment: This is correct. The default value for the toString() method of the Guid class is to add dashes. You can change this behaviour in your C# code by passing the format parameter to the toString method, see the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx)

Comment: @Jan-Henk ...or you could just not bother with the GUID bit at all, and get the string straight out of `MD5CryptoServiceProvider`...

Comment: Haha indeed, what was I thinking :)